# Counting in thirds on Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Out of curiousity, is there a way on Python that the computer/program can count in thirds without using range, but instead with slices and indices? For example, what if you had a codon like 'CAGCAGCAT'. Could python divide that string into thirds like this: CAG CAG CAT? I tried to, but I failed. If there's a way, show me how. I'm curious

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python is related.

Comment: It's funny how the he specifically said "no range" and 4 out of 6 below use range. :)

Comment: Oh funny, I didn’t even read that. Wonder where that requirement comes from…

Comment: Even though you didn't ask for. Maybe you are interested in [Biopython](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html): Biopython is a set of freely available tools for biological computation written in Python by an international team of developers.

Answer (score 3):

```
import textwrap
textwrap.wrap('CAGCAGCAT' ,3)
```

returns

```
['CAG', 'CAG', 'CAT']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), `zip(*[iterator]*n)`, to collect items without using `range`.

```
In [96]: data = 'CAGCAGCAT'

In [97]: [''.join(grp) for grp in zip(*[iter(data)]*3)]
Out[97]: ['CAG', 'CAG', 'CAT']
```

If `len(data)` is not a multiple of 3, then the above chops off the remainder. To prevent that, use [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
In [102]: import itertools as IT
In [108]: [''.join(grp) for grp in IT.izip_longest(*[iter('CAGCAGCATCA')]*3, fillvalue='')]
Out[108]: ['CAG', 'CAG', 'CAT', 'CA']
```

---

By the way, grouper recipe works with *any* iterator. `textwrap.wrap` works only with strings. Moreover, the grouper recipe is faster:

```
In [100]: %timeit textwrap.wrap(data, 3)
10000 loops, best of 3: 17.7 µs per loop

In [101]: %timeit [''.join(grp) for grp in zip(*[iter(data)]*3)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.78 µs per loop
```

Also note that `textwrap.wrap` may not group your string into groups of 3 characters if the string contains spaces:

```
In [42]: textwrap.wrap('I am a hat', 3)
Out[42]: ['I', 'am', 'a', 'hat']
```

Comment: No range, impressive!

Comment: this is my favorite way to do it (although it can leave off some end items if the length is not `0 (mod n)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: True; in that case, use `itertools.izip_longest`.

Comment: +1 lol I never thought of that I usually just tack on `+ data[-len(data)%n:]`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = 'CAGCAGCAT'
>>> [''.join(g) for g in zip(s[::3], s[1::3], s[2::3])]
['CAG', 'CAG', 'CAT']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list comprehension, the third parameter of range is a step:

```
>>> s = "CAGCAGCAT"
>>> [s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]
['CAG', 'CAG', 'CAT']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `grouper` [`itertools` recipe](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
>>> s = 'CAGCAGCAT'
>>> list(grouper(s, 3))
[('C', 'A', 'G'), ('C', 'A', 'G'), ('C', 'A', 'T')]
```

Or in your case, you can also use simple slices:

```
>>> [s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]
['CAG', 'CAG', 'CAT']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in xrange(0, len(seq), size))
```

Stolen from [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)